# How can I query my API in React in a way that has dynamically defined queries?

Tags: reactjs, django, rest, graphql, protocol-buffers

I'm using Django Rest Framework and React, but this is more of a conceptual question.

I've noticed that when querying data from an API, especially on a React-esque frontend, I always run into the same issues.

1. API responses are not intrinsically typed
2. I cannot specific *exactly* what fields I'd like to get back from the API
3. I can't specify dynamic type-safe filtering and sorting.

In an ideal world, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
// Using a user model as an example.
export function UserComponent(props: ...){

  // `data` is inferred to be of type Pick<User, "email", "lastActive">
  const data = myCustomAPIFetch<User>({
    model: User 
    fields: [User.email, User.lastActive],
    filters: {
      [User.firstName]: "Linus"
    } // Similar syntax for sorting
  })

  return (...)
}
```

This solves all three issues - it returns the proper type object, filtering/sorting is type-safe, and the exact fields that I want back can be specified.

The solutions that I've researched here solve *some* of the problems, but not all.

Graphql - solves #2 and can solve #1, but from what I understand I have to make a new query/resolver for each filter or sort I want to do. Not ideal.

Protobuf - types are cross-language (huge plus), but can only specify a static schema. Can't ask for only the user's email back without making a new message type.

tRPC - only for TS stacks, also doesn't solve #2 or #3.

Comment: Well, a graphql server could also be constructed in such a way that the schema/resolvers are _generated_ from known facts about what sorting/filtering is available on the back end.  You don't have to manually define the schema and resolvers upfront if you don't want. You can invert it. Thats just an impl consideration and is very possible, and is on the same basis of all the libs that do "give me a gql server on top of my db schema".

Comment: You can probably achieve something similar with generating OpenAPI specs and using the language specific generators on top of it but I'm going to save you a lot of pain and inform you the TS generators for OpenAPI all suck with loads of edge cases because OpenAPI is not a great format for type gen. I've been bitten so very hard by that specific challenge in the past.  There is also https://buildwithfern.com/docs/comparison-with-openapi to get around that for Rest APIs though.

Comment: GraphQL solves #1 and #2, but #3 is more of an implementation problem. You GraphQL API could define filters and sorting for all properties (and there are some GraphQL frameworks that offer that, e.g. Hasura, Postgraphile, ...) but it is regarded an anti-pattern to expose sorting and filtering for every property. The reason is that these sorts and filters might be slow if not backed by an index. This is of course a large company/organisation concern and you might be free to ignore that.

Comment: You could also consider something like Supabase: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/using-filters which offers SQL like queries on the client side. But again, you are moving backend logic into the frontend which is fine for smaller projects but can be difficult to manage at scale. Either way, I would recommend something that already exists, because building something so flexible can be a lot of work.